# Separate json encoded array result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

The following php block searches and returns names and i want to select an item and at ajax be able to get other items in the row selected beside "name". How do i separate them with ajax?

```
<?php
require_once '../php/db_conx.php';
$req = "SELECT name "
    ."FROM profiles "
    ."WHERE name LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' "; 
$query = mysql_query($req);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($results);

?>
```

Here's ajax.

```
$(function() {
        $( "#SearchInput").autocomplete({
source: 'Search.php',
minLength: 1,
select: function(event, ui) {
$('#Name').append(ui.item.label);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to get more than just name into the JSON or are you asking how to parse the JSON to get other values?

Comment: @Nick how to parse the JSON to get other values, Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample of your JSON?

Comment: that's all i have, i use that to display my search.

Comment: No one can tell you how to parse your JSON if they don't know how it's structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [_renderItem method](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem)

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {       
    $( "#selector" ).text( item.name );// let name is in json
}
```

Or you can get the `name` in [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) also like,

```
select: function(event, ui) {
   $('#Name').append(ui.item.label);
   $( "#selector" ).text( item.name );// let name is in json
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
I think you need to parse data from array.

var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);
document.write(contact.surname + ", " + contact.firstname);

Use the variable name you have used. 
Read More on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx
```

- Thanks